# Does GM_xmlhttpRequest access the website as if I am accessing the website in my browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I am curious as to how `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` reads a page in certain situations.
Does GM_xmlhttpRequest access the website as if I am accessing the website in my browser?

Do sessions remain valid? For example: If I log into a website from one browser tab and then, from another tab, I send a GM_xmlhttpRequest from my script, is this new request also logged in?

One reason I ask is because at one point in my script I am sending a GM_xmlhttpRequest to one of my domain's pages that reports back the `REMOTE_ADDR` from PHP. This is reporting back my computer's IP (which is what I want) instead of the page I am calling this function from.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

OMG it totally does!!!!!!

```
var server2="http://www.somesiteimloggedinto.com";
var test_data=function(){
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: server2,
        onload: function(response) {
            if(response.status == 200){
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        onerror: function(response) {
            console.log("Connection to "+server2+" failed.");
        }
    });
};
test_data();
```

Answer (score 4):

> Does GM_xmlhttpRequest access the website as if I am accessing the website in my browser? As in, do sessions remain valid?

Yes and no.
Normally, `GM_xmlhttpRequest` looks just like a Firefox request to the URL. [It sends the usual headers and it *normally* sends any cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373712/331508).  And, yes, the request is coming from your browser, so it reports your IP address.  This means that any sessions you have with a web page are usually preserved.

However:

1. If the URL is **cross-domain** to the webpage and you have **disabled *third-party cookies***, [then `GM_xmlhttpRequest` will NOT send cookies](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1521#issuecomment-4454812) and the target site won't know about any session you have with it.
2. `GM_xmlhttpRequest` loads only the requested URL.  If it is a web page any: images, CSS files, JS files, etc. -- that the web page calls -- will not be loaded nor processed.  Any embedded javascript in the page will not be run.

   See ["How to get an AJAX get-request to wait for the page to be rendered before returning a response?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11486256/331508) for more information and tips if you need to fetch an AJAX-powered site.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. Images are in fact handled as html code. This is seen when making a cross domain request where images from Domain B, which are relatively linked, try to make a request for said image on Domain A, causing a 404 if no link to requested file exists on Domain A. The images however are, of course, not processed in the sense of streaming images from network to network.